# Unable to get client side validation working in ASP.NET Core (7.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have an ASP.NET Core (7.0) web app and I'm unable to get client side validation to work in VS2022 (17.6.2 - 64 bit, Win 10). I'm expecting to see a validation message on screen as I type or if I cause the input box to loose focus but I see no validation text. I type in a number outside the range or an invalid format email address. There are no errors in the browser console window.

What am I doing wrong?

I created a new ASP.NET Core project, added some properties to the model on the template Privacy page and then added the elements to the page and included _ValidationScriptsPartial. The 3 jQuery .js files are included from the Layout or _ValidationScriptsPartial. I expect to see a validation message but I don't.

Model:

```
 public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [Range(0, 50, ErrorMessage = "Number is invalid")]
        public int TestNumber { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email address is invalid")]        
        public string TestString { get; set; }

        public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
@page
@model PrivacyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>

<label asp-for="TestNumber" >Enter number</label>
<input id="idtn" name="testn" type="text" asp-for="TestNumber" />
<span asp-validation-for="TestNumber"/>

<label asp-for="TestString" >Enter string</label>
<input id="idts" name="tests" type="text" asp-for="TestString" />
<span asp-validation-for="TestString" />

@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given code, it looks like the issue is within the `name` property of the `input` tag. `asp-validation-for` will try to find the `input` tag with the name `TestNumber` but the name is `testn`.
Try the below code, it should work:

```
<input id="idtn" name="TestNumber" type="text" asp-for="TestNumber" />
<span asp-validation-for="TestNumber"/>
```

You can remove the `name` property; `asp-for` will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting to see a validation message on screen as I type or if I
> cause the input box to loose focus but I see no validation text. I
> type in a number outside the range or an invalid format email address.
> There are no errors in the browser console window.
>
> What am I doing wrong?

Actually, in asp.net core ragardless of its version the client side validation take place based on `asp-validation-for` which should be same as property defination. Other than, `asp-validation-for` and `asp-for` no additional attributes are required for implementing validation stuff. Thus, your `id` and `name` property doing nothing and causing miss-match issue for `asp-for` and `asp-validation-for` because these has defined as TestNumber but id and name are different. Same goes for other property as well.

Although, `id` and `name` property is not mandatory or unncessary within your scenario but still you can use it, thus, the point is that, these values should be matched with property defination which are TestNumber and TestString  followed by `asp-validation-for` and `asp-for`.

Let's have a look, how we can achieve that in practice:

**cshtml:**

```
    @page
    @model PrivacyModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
    }
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TestNumber"  class="control-label pt-2"></label>
            <input asp-for="TestNumber" id="TestNumber" name="TestNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TestNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TestString" class="control-label pt-2"></label>
            <input asp-for="TestString" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TestString" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <br />
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    @section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**cshtml.cs:**

```
public class PrivacyModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<PrivacyModel> _logger;

        public PrivacyModel(ILogger<PrivacyModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [Range(5, 50, ErrorMessage = "Number is invalid")]
        public int TestNumber { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email address is invalid")]
        public string TestString { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
           
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Razor Pages Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#validation) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) In addition, you can check [Built-in validation attributes within razor page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-attributes)